# Setting Up a Backup on an External HD with Backup Exec

Tags: backup, external

I have been trying to set up a back up on Symantec Back Up Exec 10d and it is not working. I have the external HD formatted into a NTFS and Mounted to the O:\ drive but it does not show up in the "Devices" tab. I added it as a removable storage device, but it only created the folder with nothing else in it. Everytime I run the test I receive the error saying "No online Media". Does anyone know what could be causing the device not the register?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the device as "online" after enabling it?

Comment: I went into Disk Manager and it says "Healthy(Active)". Is there somewhere else I would have to enable it?

Comment: If you actually right click on the external drive from within the "Devices" section, you should be able to click on "Online"

Comment: When I right click on the device the only options are "Disable, Uninstall, Update Drivers". I already updated the drivers as well.

Comment: Do you have proper authentication credentials to access the drive?

Comment: I should, I am on the administrator account

Comment: You generally need to add those credentials into BackupExec.  So that BackupExec can be authenticated to access the drive.  Should be "System Account Credentials" or something.  Make sure that it has domain admin access.

Comment: I've decided to insert a quarter stick of dynamite into the server because I don't feel like dealing with this anymore. Thanks for your help anyway.